# Get the destination URL only without loading the contents with cURL

Tags: php, curl, redirect, header

If I visit the website `https://example.com/a/abc?name=jack`, I get redirected to `https://example.com/b/uuid-123`. I want only the end URL which is `https://example.com/b/uuid-123`. The contents of `https://example.com/b/uuid-123` is about 1mb but I am not interested in the content. I only want the redirected URL and not the content. How can I get the redirected URL without having to also load the 1mb of content which wastes my bandwidth and time.

I have seen a few questions about redirection on stackoverflow but nothing on how not to load the content.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://example.com/a/abc?name=jack');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_exec($ch);
$end_url = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
curl_close($ch);

echo('End URL is ' . $end_url);
```

Comment: What's stopping you from just retrieving the header with `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);`? You could then parse the headers for the `location` header.

Comment: I didn't know this existed. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For clarity i'll add it as an answer as well.

You can tell curl to only retrieve the headers by setting the `CURLOPT_NOBODY` to `true`.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
```

From these headers you can parse the `location` part to get the redirected URL.

Edit for potential future readers: `CURLOPT_HEADER` will also need to be set to `true`, i had left this out as you already had it included in your code.